# lossing memory after running series of queries over and over

Tags: mysql, server-administration

I have sql script that contains `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE, INSERT INTO...SELECT, DROP TEMPORARY TABLE`. As I run this script over and over, my used memory (RAM) increases until an error says MySQL server has gone away. What could be the reason? I was thinking the memory used gets back to its previous size soon as the temporary table has been dropped.

Comment: Do you have some entries in your error log? Normally if you MySQL crashes you should be an entry with an error.

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` defaults to create a disk based temporary table unless you use `ENGINE=MEMORY` as option..  `MySQL server has gone away` could be caused by too little off free disk space.